# Save file to App_Data folder error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to save a pdf file generated using Rotativa to the app_data folder of my web app but I get the error :

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\www\tsp13amp\website.com\wwwroot\App_Data\Documents\Corps_Profile_userID.pdf'.
```

My Controller code :

```
var PDF = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("ProfilePrint", model) { FileName = "Corps_Profile_" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")};

            var fileName = PDF.FileName;
            byte[] pdfBytearray = PDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

            var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Documents/"),fileName +".pdf");
            var byteArray = PDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, byteArray)
```

What I am trying to do is to store the file in the App_Data folder and a reference to the file in the database which will then be used a link to the file later on like:

```
 <a href="~/App_Data/Documents/File.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: And the ```Documents``` folder exists below the ```App_Data``` folder?

Comment: Try using any other folder. I don't think you can do this in appdata folder

Comment: does `Documents` folder exists inside `App_Data` folder.

Comment: It didn't exist. For some reason when publishing the App_Data folder didnt publish as well. Decided to create a new folder outside of App_Data to store the files though. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make this official - don't store anything in your app_data unless you specifically have a way it will be used. This folder is not mapped by default to return content, as such you'd need an HttpHandler or something specific to serve files from this folder. If you map them to a name in the database you'd still need a way to return them.

You are much better served creating another folder to use for this.